# Not getting Stack Overflow Notifications

Tags: bug, status-completed, global-inbox, achievements-dialog

I am not getting notifications badges despite the fact that I have 4 notifications.

I got comments on my question, but because of this I didn't know that someone had commented on my question.

I am using Chrome on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: You mean your inbox isn't working? Or the achievements box? (there are two different boxes). Are your websockets working? Do the notifications show when you open a new page or reloaded a page?

Comment: no it never shows, also i didn't get for your comment also.

Comment: Confirmed, the boxes don't highlight correctly. The inbox doesn't highlight at all, the achievements box only goes green.

Comment: Confirmed on Meta.SE as well: [Achievements indicator no longer showing number for rep change](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239641)

Comment: Seems to be fixed now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anna Lear confirmed the issue and [reverted the change that broke this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239691):

> just an errant CSS change. Reverted the commit and presto

Comment: It was strange.  Yesterday my green rep box changed to the green bars.  So every time I got an upvote, it looked as it would if I got a badge.  And then this morning I had 14 comments.  I thought I had really screwed up an answer.  Haha