# Not receiving notifications

Tags: bug, status-norepro, notifications

Last time I see this reported was from Sep 2014:
[Not getting Stack Overflow Notifications](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271765/not-getting-stack-overflow-notifications)

I haven't been getting any **Achievement Inbox** notifications for the past couple days. I do get them in my normal Inbox (answers, comments, etc.) but not for points.

Only noticed on StackOverflow, not sure if it's affecting other sites

latest Chrome on both Ubuntu and OSX

Comment: Just a thought, I recently broke 5,000 rep but then placed a 100 bounty on one of my questions. Possibly related? I don't think I noticed it before then

Comment: You don't get notified of negative changes since your last view of the achievements menu. So if you spent 100 points on a bounty, then never checked the achievements menu again, it would not show you anything until you received more than 100 points. This should be reset by simply checking the achievements menu. If it does not, then it may be a bug.

Comment: Just to be clear - what do you mean by "not getting notifications"? Is the number of points gained not showing up in the top bar or are you expecting something else?

Comment: @TinyGiant I just checked the achievements menu. I am still ~75 points down so I will update if it works on my next point gain

Comment: @AdamLear The number of points is updating, but I'm not getting the little red number overlaid on the achievements icon

Comment: @TinyGiant ok confirmed, it works now that I've viewed the achievements menu

Comment: @AdamLear it works now, I just had to view the achievements menu after losing points from giving a bounty

Comment: @andrewtweber Cool. Gonna mark this no-repro for now, let me know if the issue persists.

Comment: @Adam it is kind of an edge case but it is reproducible. How hard would it be to mark the rep loss from posting a bounty as "seen" automatically?

Comment: I have [submitted a formal feature-request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313628/mark-rep-loss-from-posting-a-bounty-as-seen-automatically) for the aforementioned functionality.

Comment: @andrewtweber just for the record when you said "little red number overlaid on the achievements icon" were you talking about the red number over the *notifications* icon or the *green* colorization of the achievements icon?

Comment: @TylerH you're right, it's green. I forgot that they were different colors